# Where are files saved in gloud python app deployment.?

Tags: python, flask, gcloud

I have deployed a python flask app in google cloud which generates a json file. Here is a code snippet:

```
@app.route('/save_data', methods=['POST'])
def index():

    try:
        raw_data = request.get_json()
        print(raw_data)
        with open("data.json", 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(raw_data, fp, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        return jsonify({'Status': 'OK'}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When a user calls this api, `data.json` file is created. I can see logs using `gcloud app  logs tail -s default` and the file being created but I am not sure where it is saved. I have checked the project directory but the file is not there. Can anyone please guide me where this file is saved. Thanks

Comment: How and where have you deployed this application?

Comment: @C.Nivs on google cloud

Comment: Are you using App Engine Flexible ?

Comment: @marian.vladoi Yes. I followed this guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Cloud Storage for saving files.

[Reading and Writing Temporary Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-temp-files)

According to official documentation:

> While Cloud Storage is the recommended solution for reading and
>   writing files in App Engine, if your app only needs to write temporary
>   files, you can use standard Python 3.7 methods to write files to a
>   directory named /tmp.
>
> All files in this directory are stored in the instance's RAM,
>   therefore writing to /tmp takes up system memory. In addition, files
>   in the /tmp directory are only available to the app instance that
>   created the files. When the instance is deleted, the temporary files
>   are deleted.

Therefore your files are stored on `/tmp` folder.